# What will be the regular expression for a fixed format of alphanumeric value

Tags: regex

I have a problem where I need to see if the textbox entry is an alphanumeric value. The format for this entry Character(A-Z) then Number(0-9), where there's only one alphabet and Numbers can be as many as he wants.The lphabet should always come first.A minimum of 2 characters have to be entered.
Example is A100, A1.
It should not accept 1A.

Comment: you can do that with a regular expression! Problem solved?

Comment: This is such a fundamental question, you would be better off spending an hour studying regular expressions than to have someone give you the answer. Regular expressions aren't hard to learn, and what you need to do is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Where can I learn about Regular Expressions

Comment: in the reference manual of the language you are using. Or, just use google. There are probably hundreds of free tutorials on the web. Spend just one day dedicated to learning regular expressions and you'll never have to ask another regex question for the rest of your career. That's a pretty good return on your investment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[A-Z][0-9]+$
```

The above means, starting at the beginning of the string, one character in the set A_Z, followed by one or more characters in the set 0-9, followed by the end of the string.

Comment: I tried your solution.It accepts 2A as valid input.It shouldn't.

Comment: @gizgok: I think you are mistaken. The above absolutely won't match 2A. The pattern very specifically is looking for a letter followed by one or more digits. You must be calling your regular expression function wrong, or interpreting the results wrong.

Comment: That is quite possible.But it ain't working.This is what is working [^A-Z0-9].

Comment: @gizgok: the pattern you chose says that the first character must be A-Z or 0-9. It will match all sorts of things that aren't what you originally asked for. You are on the right path thinking about using ^. I've modified my answer to include anchors, since you want to match against a whole string. Try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: Event eh changed answer doesn't work.It's accepting 1e1 as valid input which is even more baffling